# Numerical integration involving Inverse Normal CDF

Tags: numerical-integration, distributions

I'd like to evaluate the following numerical integration using *Mathematica*

$$
\ \int_0^T\int_0^\infty xe^{-0.04 s}g(x,s) dxds\ 
$$

where g(x,s) is a Gaussian copula function with say, marginal exponential distributions with parameter A and parameter B (i.e. X~exp(A) and S~exp(B)). In the following MMA attempt, the g(x,s) is defined by GE[Theta,A,B].

This is what I've tried so far:

```
GE[Theta_, A_, B_] := CopulaDistribution[{"Binormal", Theta}, {ExponentialDistribution[A],ExponentialDistribution[B]}];

Delta = 0.04; A = 0.10; B = 10; Theta = 0.9; T=5;
GExpExp[x_,s_] := PDF[GE[Theta, A, B], {x, s}]

NIntegrate[Exp[-Delta*s]*x GExpExp, {x, 0, Infinity}, {s, 0, T}]
```

and the following is the error I obtain:

**NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 1.1547 E^(-10 s-0.1 x-s [Delta]+2 InverseErfc[2 \
Plus[<<2>>]]^2-1.33333 (0.707107 InverseErfc[<<1>>]-Power[<<2>>] \
InverseErfc[<<1>>])^2)* x has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in
the region with boundaries {{0.05`,36},{0.5`,1}}. >>*

I then try to integrate the expression with respect to only one variable, in this case I chose variable x, so that I'd end up with a univariate expression (and hence I might be able to work on a simpler problem from then on)

```
  Integrate[Exp[-Delta*s]*GExpExp1[x, s], {x, 0, Infinity}]

  (* 11.547 E^(-10.04 s + 1.33333 InverseErfc[4 - 4 E^(-10 s)]^2) *)
```

It seems that eventually I still have to deal with the Inverse[NormalDistribution] function, which I think is the source of this issue. I then continued with the following:

```
  T = 5; 
  Assuming[s > 0, LaplaceTransform[NIntegrate[11.547005383792516` E^(-10.04` s + 1.3333333333333337` InverseErfc[4 - 4 E^(-10 s)]^2), {s, 0, T}], s, T]]

  (* NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 11.547 E^(-10.04 s+1.33333 InverseErfc[4+Times[<<2>>]]^2) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1.,2}}. >>  *)
```

It could be because the function does not converge, but even after reducing the limit interval from [0,T] to [2,3] (and of course changing T to 5 instead of 2) I still can't obtain a number. Does anyone know the correct syntax that I should use so that I can obtain a numerical answer eventually? Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Certainly, `T` is not a number, and you do not seem to have assigned a value to it...

Comment: Instead of `GExpExp = PDF[GE[\[Theta], A, B, {x, s}]` .. use: `GExpExp = PDF[GE[Theta, A, B], {x, s}]`  ... note the different placement of the closing brackets ]  ... and then you will need to choose a value for T too, or set up `K[T] := NIntegrate[ blah]` .... not ....  `K[T] = NIntegrate[ ...]`

Comment: You still haven't addressed the thing @wolfies was pointing out. In any event, `K` is a built-in reserved symbol, so please do not use it to denote your function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors guys. I have edited the question by including the value of parameter T as well as have written the correct expression of PDF[GE[Theta,A,B]] like how it appears in my code.

Comment: @0x4A4D, can you please tell me if there's other wrong syntax? I'll edit them so that the readers can understand my question and provide ideas to generate solution. Thank you.

Comment: There does indeed appear to be a problem here now (after everything has been fixed up) ... mma 9 hangs or kernel crashes on my Mac. You can force it to produce an answer by adding an option such as `NIntegrate[blah, Method -> "MonteCarlo"]` ... but, in  any event, it would appear that the integral does not converge.

Comment: That's why I thought the issue stems from the InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0,1],1-Exp[-0.1*x]] command

Comment: You are invoking `GExpExp` inside the integral without giving it explicit parameters `x` and `s`. It thus won't evaluate to a number.

Answer (score 1):

If I use exact coefficients, I get an exact answer with `Integrate` after a couple of minutes:

```
GE[Theta_, A_, B_] := 
  CopulaDistribution[{"Binormal", Theta}, {ExponentialDistribution[A],
     ExponentialDistribution[B]}];

Delta = 4/100; A = 10/100; B = 10; Theta = 90/100; T = 5;
GExpExp[x_, s_] := PDF[GE[Theta, A, B], {x, s}]

Integrate[Exp[-Delta*s]*GExpExp[x, s], {x, 0, Infinity}, {s, 0, T}]
(*
  (250 (-1 + E^(251/5)))/(251 E^(251/5))
*)
```